# How do I save configuration files in different branches of Mercurial?

Tags: merge, mercurial, branching-and-merging

I have a problem with saving different config files in my `Mercurial` repository. For example, I have 2 branches - `dev` and `testing`. For each, I have my Jenkinsfile (configuration of Jenkins pipeline). It also could be any other configuration files (DB config, other systems configs) that are different between branches. Each time when I merge `testing` with `dev` I should merge the Jenkinsfile manually. How could I solve this problem? I wanna save the history of my config files and don't wanna have any problems with merging. Is there any approach to solve this routine problem?

Comment: you could create a second repo, one directory up, that just contains config files and ignored everything else. Then remove and ignore config files the main repo.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It sounds like a good solution. And it definitely solve the problem of merging. But it creates a lot of problems with ci system (with Jenkins in my case).

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick:

When you hit the merge conflict (obviously, you will see conflict every time when merging these two branches with a config file with the same name but different content) you can perform a re-merge only for that config file while also using the `--tool` flag to tell the "merge machine" that we want to keep the local version of this file, by running:

`hg resolve path/to/config/file --re-merge --tool ':local'`

Or short version: `hg res path/to/config/file --re-merge -t ':local'`

Note: `hg merge` also has this `--tool` option but be careful using that because it would apply that merge-tool to every file that will be merged in that operation.

To know more about merge tools, run: `hg help merge-tools`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest, It sounds more like a workaround solution. And I should use hg resolve each time during the merge. It's still a problem. And I should to "say" my colleagues about this approach each time. No information about the" special status " of the configuration file is saved in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial a lot of time have concepts of custom merge tools and merge-patterns (see `MergeTools.rc` and `MergePatterns.rc`)

I.e. you can for your Jenkinsfile (even it haven't unique perrepository extension, give it) custom mergetool, which will do just `hg merge --tool internal:local`